# In pygame, what is the most efficient way of resetting every sprite's position?

Tags: python, pygame, pyscripter

I'm trying to make a **typical platformer using pygame** but I'm not exactly sure how I should go about doing a death sequence. I want it so after time the player dies every sprite's position is reset to its original position if they moved at all.

I tried experimenting with the `pygame.sprite.Group().copy()` but I don't know how to use it or if it even applies to my situation.

Comment: better create function `reset()` in every sprite and run `for`-loop to run `reset()` for every sprite in group. If you copy then you get vaues with current values, not reseted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store a copy of the original position in the sprite, and then as @furas suggests re-position and re-stat the sprite via a `reset()` function.

For example:

```
class ResettableSprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    MAX_HEALTH = 100
    def __init__( self, image, x, y ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        self.image   = image
        self.rect    = self.image.get_rect()
        self.start_x = x
        self.start_y = y
        self.reset()

    def reset( self ):
        self.rect.x = self.start_x
        self.rect.y = self.start_y
        self.health = ResettableSprite.MAX_HEALTH
        # ... etc.
```

Comment: Oh yeah I never thought of it like that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help.